# Make a UserScope with Dagger2 that lives for multiple activities and fragments

Tags: android, android-activity, dagger-2, dagger

I want to make a UserScope with Dagger 2 that provides a User for several Activities. When the User log-in, Dagger inject the User to these activities, and once the User log-out, the instance must be null until the next log-in.
this is what i did so far:
the user scope:

```
@Scope
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface UserScope {
}
```

the user component:

> Dagger generate error saying that BaseActivity should be a module

```
@UserScope
@Subcomponent(
        modules = {
                UserModule.class,
                NetworkModule.class
        }
)
public interface UserComponent {

        UserComponent inject(BaseActivity activity);
}
```

and the UserModule

```
@Module
public class UserModule {

    private User user;

    public UserModule(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    @Provides
    @UserScope
    FirebaseUser provideUser() {


  return user;
}
```

}

Should I make a Module activity for each activity that needs User ??

Comment: Here is an article that might help: http://frogermcs.github.io/dependency-injection-with-dagger-2-custom-scopes/

Comment: I saw this article, in fact each Activity is a self module, which generates a lot of classes. I am looking for a better solution

Comment: You're using Dagger 2 wrong so please spend some more time reading the tutorials. Inject methods inside Components have to have return type `void`. So write `void inject(BaseActivity activity);`

Comment: @DavidRawson yes that's right, and i musn't put BaseActivity as parameter, It must the real activity cuz Dagger must know the target Activity in COmpile time

Comment: There isn't really a 'better solution' than the one that frogermcs proposed I'm afraid. If you don't like writing classes I suppose you can choose not to use Dagger 2. In fact, it's probably overkill for a small project