# @UserScope with dagger-android

Tags: android, dagger-2, dagger

I have been forcing myself to use `dagger-android` for my new project, in order to reduce all the boiler plate for subComponents for activities and fragments.

But struggling with getting my `@UserScope` deps to be injected in those activities.

Reading up dagger-android it seems to support this kind of object graph:

`Application -> Activity -> Fragment -> Sub-fragments`

In my case I need a UserScope to sit between Application and Activity. i.e

```
                      |-> Activity -> Fragment -> Sub-fragments`
Application -> User - |
                      |-> Activity -> Fragment -> Sub-fragments`
```

I was wondering if there is way to achieve this WITH using `ContributesAndroidInjector` along with a custom subcomponent.

Any advice.

Couple of similar threads:

- [Make a UserScope with Dagger2 that lives for multiple activities and fragments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46214679/make-a-userscope-with-dagger2-that-lives-for-multiple-activities-and-fragments)
- https://github.com/google/dagger/issues/1267

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `AndroidInjection` and `ContributesAndroidInjector` I don't think that is possible, if not in some degenerate way.

To be more precise, when you use `AndroidInjection` the code is getting the Application instance from your class, and then using the `HasActivityInjector` the App has.
Therefore the activities' sub-components must be sub-components of the Component which injected the `Application` class at startup.

And when the `Application` class is created you can't really be in a scope different than an Application/singleton scope.

Probably the question is: what is in the User scope (and not in the application scope) and where does that come from?

- If you can get that when the app starts before starting any activities, then just merge the application and the user components.
- If you 'create' then user scope from some data you get from, say, an activity, then you'll have the activities pass some data using intents when they launch each other.